# File type not sending with python requests file uploading

Tags: python-requests

I am trying to upload a file using python requests, but when I try to post the file the file type not there.

```
import requests, json, time

session = requests.Session()

with open("./error2.jpg", 'rb') as f:
    res = session.post("http://rayinrice.com/upload/", files={"files": f})
    print("Status Code: *" + str(res.status_code))
    print("\nContent:\n" + res.content)
```

### RESPONSE FROM SERVER

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `files` parameter in `request.post()`. You can do this by doing the following.

```
files = {'files': open('error2.jpg','rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```